# How to get xml output from running grunt jasmine

Tags: junit, jasmine, gruntjs

I'm trying to get my test integrated into bamboo. With bamboo, it seems that I need test  results to be in junit xml format. Because of this, I need to get my "grunt jasmine" execution to output test results in xml format. I'm new to jasmine/grunt/junit and have spent more time than I care to admit trying to get this to work. I've followed various tutorials and boards (mostly https://gist.github.com/asabaylus/3059886), but am just stuck.

When I run "grunt jasmine" from gitbash, The specs run successfully, but no output file is produced and I get the following error...
" An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot call method 'indexO
f' of undefined). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings."

Do I have to change any other files? Can anyone please help me work through this?

Please and thanks!
CC

**grunt.js file**

```
/*global module:false*/
    module.exports = function ( grunt ) {

        // Project configuration.
        grunt.initConfig({
            meta: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
                    '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
                    '<%= pkg.homepage ? "* " + pkg.homepage + "\n" : "" %>' +
                    '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %>;' +
                    ' Licensed <%= _.pluck(pkg.licenses, "type").join(", ") %> */'
            },

            lint: {
                files: ['grunt.js', 'src/**/*.js']
            },

            jasmine: {
                all: ['./SpecRunner.html'],
                junit: {
                    dest: 'test-results' 
                }  
            },

            concat: {
                dist: {
                    src : ['<banner:meta.banner>', '<file_strip_banner:src/buyitnow.js>'],
                    dest: 'dist/buyitnow/<%= meta.version %>/buyitnow.js'
                }
            },

            min: {
                dist: {
                    src : ['<banner:meta.banner>', '<config:concat.dist.dest>'],
                    dest: 'dist/buyitnow/<%= meta.version %>/buyitnow.min.js'
                }
            },

            watch: {
                files: '<config:lint.files>',
                tasks: 'lint'
            },

            jshint: {
                options: {
                    curly  : true,
                    eqeqeq : true,
                    immed  : true,
                    latedef: true,
                    newcap : true,
                    noarg  : true,
                    sub    : true,
                    undef  : true,
                    boss   : true,
                    eqnull : true,
                    browser: true,
                    jquery : true,
                    node   : true
                },
                globals: {}
            },

            uglify: {}
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-task');

        // Default task.
        grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint jasmine concat min cssmin');};
```

**My specrunner.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine.async.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/sinon-1.6.0.js"></script>

  <!-- For JUnit output of test results include the following link to Lary Myer's JUnit reporter -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jasmine-reporters/src/jasmine.junit_reporter.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/binSpec.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
      jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

      var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
      jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

      // Specify target test results folder as below, for now
      var junitReporter = new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('test-results/');
      jasmineEnv.addReporter(junitReporter);

      jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
      };

      var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;

      window.onload = function() {
        if (currentWindowOnload) {
          currentWindowOnload();
        }
        execJasmine();
      };

      function execJasmine() {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
      }

    })();
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Amir T said, you can use [`grunt-contrib-jasmine`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine). Moreover, `grunt-jasmine-task` is not longer active.

The [`options.junit.path`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine#optionsjunitpath) option can be used for creating junit reports that can then be used by Jenkins/Hudson, Travis, Bamboo, etc. This option should provide the name of the folder where the reports are going to be created (`grunt-contrib-jasmine` will create an xml for each spec file). This is an example configuration:

```
jasmine: {
    tests: {
        src: 'dist/buyitnow/<%= meta.version %>/buyitnow.min.js',
        options: {
            specs: 'spec/*Spec.js',
            junit: {
                path: 'build/junit'
            },
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to create an `SpecRunner.html` file as it's created automatically by `grunt-contrib-jasmine`

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do this using grunt-contrib-jasmine@0.5.2

```
jasmine: {
  pivotal: {
    src: 'build/application.js',
    options: {
      specs: 'test/**/*_spec.js',
      helpers: 'test/**/*_helper.js',
      junit: {
        path: 'build/.test'
      },
    }
  }
}
```